# envio por ajax, solo me muestra una columna

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabla-dinámica

Tengo el siguiente código, en el trato de enviar a un archivo php el nombre de una tabla y que me devuelva sus columnas. Quiero acabar metiendolo en un array de javascript, pero solo me muestra los campos de una columna y no entiendo porque.

```js
function dimenombres() 
{ 
 tabla = dimetabla();
 const yourData = {
    describe: tabla
 };
 console.log(tabla);
  $.ajax ({ type: 'POST',
  url: 'userAction.php',
  data: yourData,
  success:function(response) 
  { 
 console.log(response);
  },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
  {
   alert(xhr.status);
   alert(thrownError);
 } 
 }); 
}
```

```html
    if(!empty($_POST['describe']))
    {
     $nombrecolumnas = $db->describe($_POST['describe']);
     echo json_encode($nombrecolumnas);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Lo de la imagen es lo que te muestra en el console.log(`response)`?

Comment: si, si pongo response.nombrecolumnas devuelve indefinido

Comment: ¿Y la consola del navegador te lo saca así? Se me hace muy raro ese formateo.

Comment: si porque tengo un `console.log(tabla)` y luego el `console.log(response)`

Comment: Yo veo todas las columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he dado con el error, como trabajo con una base de datos portugesa los caraceteres de las columnas no pueden ser cogidos por el sql.

Los caracteres no pertenecian al UTF-8 por lo que se mostrabas símbolos extraños que el select no era capaz de leer y recogia como null o vacio.

Comment: En ese caso lo mejor es que elimines la pregunta o hagas una respuesta completa explicando el problema (por si a otra persona le puede ser útil)

Comment: Podes aclarar entonces cual fue la solucion? asi como esta, no dices como se soluciona el problema.